# Hive SQL: How to split a single field into multiple columns with defined length?

Tags: sql, hive

For example: string = 'ABCDEFGHIJ'

Now, need to split the string to multiple columns with length of 4

Desired Output:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
'ABCD' 'EFGH' 'IJ'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr()`:

```
select substr(col, 1, 4) as col1, substr(col, 5, 4) as col2, substr(col, 9, 4) as col3
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. In my real data, the values in the fields vary.  For example, row 1 is 10-char string, row 2 is 18-char string, and so on. Any idea how to do it based on a standardized logic?

Comment: @JohnGame . . . A SQL query has a fixed set of columns.  You can just repeat the `substr()` up to the number of columns you want.  Otherwise, you'll need to use dynamic SQL.